# Showing same bitmap image nxt to eachother on single window

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, msdn

I have a window, based on user input I have to show the same bitmap next to each other on the same window.
Suppose say user gives 1 as input.So I have to display the image only once such tht it covers complete window
If user gives 2 as input then I have to display same image nxt to each other on the same window.So half of window will be loaded with image and next half with same image again.

Here is what I tried

```
RECT rect;
HDC hDC = GetDC(hwnd);
hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
::SelectObject(hMemDC, bmp);
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
SetStretchBltMode(hDC,HALFTONE);
// when input is one
StretchBlt(hDC, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, hMemDC, 0,
    0,bmpdata.bmWidth, bmpdata.bmHeight,SRCCOPY);

// when input is 2 I use StretchBlt twice
StretchBlt(hDC, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right/2-1, rect.bottom/2-1, hMemDC, 0,
    0,bmpdata.bmWidth, bmpdata.bmHeight,SRCCOPY);
StretchBlt(hDC, rect.right/2,  rect.bottom/2, rect.right, rect.bottom, hMemDC, 0,
    0,bmpdata.bmWidth, bmpdata.bmHeight,SRCCOPY);
```

It displays only half the screen. Second Stretchblt doesn't have any affect

Comment: Try with `rect.Width()/2` instead of `rect.right/2` same for height also.

Comment: Rect doesnt have a width n height field

Comment: Change your second `StretchBlt` like this: `StretchBlt(hDC, rect.left + rect.right/2, rect.top + rect.bottom/2, ... ` and tell us if atleast bitmap shows.

Comment: Bitmap shows on first half.. But not on second. Even if i try to give hard coded values like if size of window s 40*40 and in first StretchBlt i give 0,0,20,20 and second with 21,21,40,40.. Still same result only half of window s loaded with image.. Shud i declare 2 memdc?

Comment: @230490 use `CRect` instead of `Rect` .